# Referencing a 64 bit DLL in T4 template

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit, t4

If I reference a 64 bit DLL in a T4 template like

```
<#@ assembly name="path\to\64bit.dll" #>
```

and run it with TextTransform.exe, it will give an exception, saying

```
There was a problem loading the assembly 'path\to\64bit.dll' The following Exception was thrown:
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///path\to64bit.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Is there a 64 bit version of TextTransform.exe around, or is there another way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like TextTemplatingFileGenerator tool run in 32 bit process and it' s impossible to import 64 bit assembly to a T4 template.

I found two  alternatives

1. to write a custom template class which inherits from TextTemplating class in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating assembly. I also think that if there exists text generations by complex code, this is better way than using tt files because it' s more understandable and manageable. Here is the example for that. 

   In a 64 bit assembly

   ```
   namespace SixtyFourBitClassLibrary
   {
       public class Class1
       {
           public string SampleString = "Sample";
       }
   }
   ```

In Main Assembly (also 64 bit)

```
    namespace ExecuteSixtyFourBitAssemblyInTT
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                SampleTemplate st = new SampleTemplate();
                var s = st.TransformText();

                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }       
        } 

        class SampleTemplate : TextTransformation
        {
            public override string TransformText()
            {
                Class1 cls = new Class1();

                return string.Format("{0} OK",cls.SampleString);
            }
        }
    }
```

2. To create a custom text template host. You can check this [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Text Template Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126579.aspx). You can use existing tt files with this method. I don' t share the code here but I checked that it' s working.

Both of the solutions require another way (maybe vs extension) to start the generation.